# How to remove specific object from an array using service in angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

Trying to remove one object which name is Test1 from the array object. I do not know how to remove that.If i did anything wrong in my code you can correct it. I have used service to update the array value.  you can understand If you check my stackblitz.
If i click the Remove Name  button i want to remove the object which name is Test1 from the array object.
So, Please help to find the solution.

dashboard.component.html:

```
<button (click)="callFun('Test1')">Remove Name</button> 
 {{ deleteItemName }}
<app-optymodel></app-optymodel>
```

dashboard.component.ts:

```
callFun(name: any) {
    this.commonService.modifyDeleteItem(name);
    this.commonService.modifyNameList(name);
    this.commonService.modifyDeleteItem('');
  }
```

common.service.ts:

```
 modifyNameList(name: string) {
 const nameList = this.nameList.getValue();
 const result = nameList.filter((x) => x.name != name); 
 this.nameList.next(result);
 }

 modifyDeleteItem(name: string) {
 this.deletedItem.next(name); 
 }
```

After cliked Remove Name button result it should be like

> const result = nameList.filter((x) => x != name);
> console.log(result);
>
> ```
> [ 
> { name: 'Test2', id: '2' },
> { name: 'Test3', id: '3' },
> { name: 'Test4', id: '4' },
> { name: 'Test5', id: '5' },
> ];
> ```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pass-table-data-to-input-property-zn22go?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fcommon.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

The code in your stackblitz is actually different than the one you showed here. The line

```js
const result = nameList.filter((x) => x != name);
```

should be

```js
const result = nameList.filter((x) => x.name !== name);
```

Then you will get an lint warning/compile error that the type is wrong because you have the name list defined as `Array<string>` while it actually should be `Array<{name: string, id: string}>`. I would recommend using a type or an interface for your content of the array.

And instead of `Array.filter` you could also use `Array.splice` if you just want to remove one item (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?retiredLocale=de#remove_1_element_at_index_3)

Comment: I told you exactly what line to change^^ I can't adapt the stackblitz. If I do it will be a separate one. And I'm not going to fix all your wrong typings ;)

Comment: != is not an issue. I have tested your code but not working.

Comment: it's not the != . the .name is missing after the x